# OpenERP accessing the database

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I know that OpenERP's architecture is made up of 3 tiers: *browser -> openerp -> database*.

For example, I installed module (ex. student module) wherein there are 3 fields:

- name,
- age and
- gender.

I entered values to them and save them.

My problem:

- how can I assure that the value I entered is save into the 3rd layer which is the database?
- How can I see this database?
- And how to use the data input into the database to use into another modules?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the save doesn't work you will see an error.  Any exception in the OpenERP layer or SQL exceptions in the database are presented back as an error message.  OpenERP using a transaction in request pattern so those database updates will either work or they won't and you will see an error.
2. Use the view and search options on the menu.  If you just want to see the data then install pgadmin3 but you shouldn't change data using this unless you know what you are doing.
3. Create a new module, in the `__openerp__.py` file declare a dependency on the student module and then just use the search/browse methods on the student model